# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.context')

Tags: reactjs

I want to achieve two things:

- I want to protect some routes so they are only accessible if the user is authenticated (works).
- I want to display different HTML depending on if the user is authenticated or not (e.g login form vs. welcome message).

I tried implementing this using Context following [this](https://dayvster.com/blog/use-context-for-auth/) tutorial.

**src/context/AuthContext.tsx**

```
import { createContext } from "react"

interface AuthContext {
    isAuth: boolean
    isLoading: boolean
}

export const AuthContext = createContext<AuthContext>({
    isAuth: false,
    isLoading: true,
})
```

**src/hooks/useAuth.ts**

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import isAuthenticated from "../utils/auth"

export const useAuth = () => {
    const [isAuth, setIsAuth] = useState(false) 
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true) 

    useEffect(() => {
        const checkAuth = async() => {
            if (await isAuthenticated()) {
                console.log("Authenticated true")
                setIsAuth(true)
            } else {
                console.log("Authenticated false")
                setIsAuth(false)
            }

            setIsLoading(false)
        }

        checkAuth()
    }, [])

    return { isAuth, isLoading }
}
```

In my **src/App.tsx** I provide the `AuthContext`.

```
import AppRouter from './routes/Routes'
import "./styles/App.sass"
import { useAuth } from "./hooks/useAuth"
import { AuthContext } from "./context/AuthContext"
import Header from "./components/Header/Header"

function App() {
    const { isAuth, isLoading } = useAuth()
    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{ isAuth, isLoading }}>
            <div className="App">
                <Header />
                
                <main className="App-content">
                    <AppRouter />
                </main>
            </div>
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
}

export default App
```

In **src/routes/Routes.tsx** I use the hook to create a protected route.

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext, createContext } from "react"
import { useAuth } from "../hooks/useAuth"
import Home from "../views/Home"
import Panel from "../views/Panel"

const ProtectedRoute = ({Component} : { Component: React.ComponentType }) => {
    
    const { isAuth, isLoading } = useAuth()

    if (isLoading) {
        console.log("Is loading")
        return null
    }

    console.log("isAuthenticated? " + isAuth)

    if (!isAuth) {
        return <Navigate to="/" replace />
    }

    return <Component />
}

const AppRouter = () => {
    return (
            <Router>
                <Routes>
                    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
                    <Route path="/panel" element={<ProtectedRoute Component={Panel} />} />
                </Routes>
            </Router>
    )
}

export default AppRouter
```

Finally I want to use it in a component/view **src/views/Home.tsx** to display different HTML depending on if the user is authenticated or not.

```
import React, { Component, useContext } from 'react'
import { AuthContext } from "../context/AuthContext"
import axios from "axios"
import Cookies from "js-cookie"
import "../styles/Home.sass"

interface HomeProps {}

interface HomeState {
    message: Record<string, string>
    inputs: Record<string, string>
}

class Home extends Component<HomeProps, HomeState> {

    static contextType = AuthContext
    context!: React.ContextType<typeof AuthContext>
        
    constructor(props: HomeProps, context: React.ContextType<typeof AuthContext>) {
        super(props, context)
        
        this.state = {
            message: {},
            inputs: {},
        }

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
        this.Form = this.Form.bind(this)
    }

    componentDidMount() {

    }

    handleChange : React.ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement> = (event) => {
        let inputs = this.state.inputs
        inputs[event.target.name] = event.target.value
        this.setState({inputs})
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div id="container">
                <div id="text">
                    <div>
                        <h1>Welcome to Finonline</h1>
                        <span id="slogan">Administrate your personal expenses online.</span>
                        <p>
                            This is a demo-project for my job-application showcasing my skills in full-stack webdevelopment, Java, Spring Boot and React.js.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="form-container">
                    <this.UserGreeting />
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }

    UserGreeting() {
        const {isAuth} = this.context

        if (isAuth) {
            return (
                <div id="welcome">
                    <span className="title">Welcome </span>
                    <a href="/panel" className="button">Go to panel.</a>
                </div>
            )
        } else {
            return <this.Form />
        }
    }

    Form() {
        const handleSubmit = (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement> | React.MouseEvent<HTMLInputElement, MouseEvent>, action: string) => {
            event.preventDefault()
            
            switch (action) {
                case "register":
                    this.register(this.state.inputs)
                    break
                default:
                    this.login(this.state.inputs)
            }
        }

        return (
            <form onSubmit={(event) => handleSubmit(event, 'login')} >
                <span className="title">Login</span>
                <div className="input-wrapper">
                    <img src="/assets/images/profile.png" alt="" />
                    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Username" minLength={3} required={true} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                </div>
                <div className="input-wrapper">
                    <img src="/assets/images/password.png" alt="" />
                    <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password" minLength={5} required={true} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                </div>
                <div id="form-buttons">
                    <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" onClick={(event) => handleSubmit(event, 'login')} />
                    <input type="submit" name="register" value="Or register" id="registerbtn" onClick={(event) => handleSubmit(event, 'register')} />
                </div>
                <span id="message" className={this.state.message["type"]}>
                    { this.state.message["text"] }
                </span>
            </form>
        )
    }

    async register(data: Record<string, string>) {
        let message = this.state.message

        try {
            const response = await axios.post(`http://127.0.0.1:8080/users`,
                    data
                ,
                {
                    insecureHTTPParser: true,
                    headers: {
                        "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    }
                })

            if (response.status == 201) {
                message["type"] = "ok"
                message["text"] = "Successfully registered."
                
                this.setState({ message  })
            } else {
                message["type"] = "error"
                message["text"] = "Error: " + response.data
                
                this.setState({ message  })
            }
        } catch (err) {
            message["type"] = "error"
            message["text"] = "Error: This user already exists."
            
            this.setState({ message  })

        }
    }

    async login(data: Record<string, string>) {
       let message = this.state.message

        try {
           const response = await axios.post(`http://127.0.0.1:8080/auth`,
                    data
                ,
                {
                    insecureHTTPParser: true,
                    headers: {
                        "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    }
                })
            if (response.status == 200) {
                message["type"] = "ok"
                message["text"] = "Login successful."
                
                this.setState({ message  })
                
                const token = response.data.token
                Cookies.set("auth-token", token, { expires: 1 })

            } else {
                message["type"] = "error"
                message["text"] = "Error: Login failed."
                
                this.setState({ message  })
            }
        } catch (err) {
            message["type"] = "error"
            message["text"] = "Error: Login failed."
           
            console.log(err)

            this.setState({ message  })
        }
    }
}

export default Home
```

Runtime error caused in the function `UserGreeting()`:

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.context')
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it already. `UserGreeting()` couldn't find `this.context` because I had to bind it in my constructor:

```
    constructor(props: HomeProps, context: React.ContextType<typeof AuthContext>) {
        super(props, context)
        
        this.state = {
            message: {},
            inputs: {},
        }

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
        this.Form = this.Form.bind(this)
        // Solved it.
        this.UserGreeting = this.UserGreeting.bind(this)
    }
```